# Is there a method for comparative morpheme analysis in historical aspect?

Tags: morphology

Is there a method for comparative morpheme analysis in historical aspect? To which degree is it accurate, if such a method exists?

When, where and who did invent it?

Comment: Linguistic terminology is not standardized and it is not clear what you are referring to. Examples of what you mean would be very helpful.

Comment: Well. I think we might have a question of terms in addition to that of method. I am curious if there is any separate method to restore morphmes (personal markers, possessive markers, case markers - for the languages having these distinctions) similar to that of restoring word stems (e.g. on the basis of language 'relatives') yet applicable exclusively for morphemes other than just stems. My idea is since morphemes might have higher frequency, there should be something special about them.

Comment: OK. You mean [**inflectional**](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf) (and maybe Derivational) affixal morphemes, then; roots are morphemes also. And there is indeed something very special about affixes. Most of the PIE affix systems have been reconstructed, using the usual comparative methods. What kind of special methodology did you have in mind?

Comment: I want to understand whether some phonemes in specific Russian words are consonant clusters traditionally regarded as two separate consonants or not. For that, I need to know the history of some words provided that history traces the historical distinction between a stem and a suffix in IE (mostly Slavic) languages. So if there is any method applicable for languages of this type, it would be of a great help to me.

Comment: For that you need the right reference works. I don't know the Slavic literature, but I know there's a lot of it and it's very thorough and reliably worked out. It seems unnecessary to try to replicate a century's research when it's all available in books (mostly written in German, French, and Russian, as I recall)

Comment: Well, I read in French and Russian, but I am a bit allergic to German. Could you please help me with some useful references for source literature? By the way, this method might be partially applicable for Uralic languages as well.

Comment: The comparative method is applicable to any language for which there is adequate data. Perhaps some Slavicist could point to some literature?

Comment: I'm sorry, they can't. Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: "I want to understand whether some phonemes in specific Russian words are consonant clusters traditionally regarded as two separate consonants or not." What Russian words do you have in mind?

Comment: Words like коляска, доска, миска, or diminutive-contemptive forms of personal names with consonant alteration like Антошка <=> Антоха; Машка <=> Маха, etc.